# Run pytest on vagrant ubuntu vm with windows as host. Import file mismatch

Tags: django, ubuntu, vagrant, pytest, pytest-django

I guess that this is a quite specific situation but I will make the question since I didn't found a relevant answer and might be useful to someone else.

The situation is this:

- Windows is the host OS.
- There is an Ubuntu VirtualBox (created with    vagrant).
- My django project folder is shared between windows and    ubuntu.
- I installed pytest (through pytest-django) both on ubuntu    and on
  my virtualenv on windows.
- If I run the `pytest` command from the windows virtualenv the tests run
  just fine
- But in the ubuntu vm terminal I can't just run the `pytest` command
  since I get the error: The program 'pytest' is currently not
  installed.
- I can run it though with `python -m pytest`. But in this case I get `import file mismatch` errors:

========================ERRORS =======================

```
_____________ ERROR collecting my_django_app/tests.py ____________

import file mismatch:
imported module 'my_django_app.tests' has this **__file__** attribute:
  C:\virtualEnvs\my_env\project_src\my_django_app\tests.py
which is not the same as the test file we want to collect:
  /vagrant/projects/project_src/my_django_app/tests.py
HINT: remove __pycache__ / .pyc files and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules
```

The message is very clear but I don't know how to overcome this issue.

I use python 2.7.9 and there is no **pycache** folder (nor ant .pyc compiled files).

Comment: [pytest issue 2042](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2042) is probably related with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to delete the cached compiled python files. These files are inside **__pycache__** folders inside the django project folder. Each django app has one **pycache** folder too.

If you run pytest in windows host, the cached compiled files contain the windows specific paths and try to import modules from there. So the cached files must be deleted. Then you can run pytest in the ubuntu VM using the command: `python -m pytest`

You can avoid the creation of the compiled files in the first place by running the python interpreter with -B option: `python -B pytest`